# Syncronous API calls

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask, controller

I'm working on an Android app by adding a new functionality that fetch and save data with API calls.

These calls are made in a Fragment. There is a call made in an AsyncTask, and I don't want to create an AsyncTask for every call, so I just try send parameters to my controlles in some function, but when I debug every time I try to make a call without using an AsyncTask, I got an IOException "Cancelled". Is there a way to do this without using AsyncTasks in the same Fragment?

This is the AsyncTask:

```
private void validateUnit(@NonNull String unitCode, final int routeId, final boolean goodCondition) {

    mUnitDetails = new UnitDetails();

    if (mFindUnitAysncTask != null) {
        mFindUnitAysncTask.cancel(true);
    }
    mFindUnitAysncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, FindUnitResponse>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgressDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected FindUnitResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
            FindUnitResponse unitResponse = mUnitController.findUnit(params[0], routeId);
            FindUnitDetailsResponse unitDetailsResponse = mUnitController.getUnitDetails(
                    unitResponse.getUnits().get(0), mUser);
            if(unitDetailsResponse.isSuccess()) {
                mUnitDetails.setBranchCode(unitDetailsResponse.getBranchCode());
                mUnitDetails.setBranchName(unitDetailsResponse.getBranchName());
                mUnitDetails.setCompanyId(unitDetailsResponse.getCompanyId());
                mUnitDetails.setEconomicNumber(unitDetailsResponse.getEconomicNumber());
                mUnitDetails.setFuelType(unitDetailsResponse.getFuelType());
                mUnitDetails.setFuelTypeId(unitDetailsResponse.getFuelTypeId());
                mUnitDetails.setFuelPrice(unitDetailsResponse.getFuelPrice());
                mUnitDetails.setModel(unitDetailsResponse.getModel());
                mUnitDetails.setBrand(unitDetailsResponse.getBrand());
                mUnitDetails.setUnitType(unitDetailsResponse.getUnitType());
                mUnitDetails.setRouteCode(unitDetailsResponse.getRouteCode());
                mUnitDetails.setRealTrips(unitDetailsResponse.getRealTrips());
                mUnitDetails.setMaximumMileageRange(unitDetailsResponse.getMaximumMileageRange());
            }
            else {
                showMessage(unitDetailsResponse.getMessage());
            }
            return unitResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(FindUnitResponse response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            dismissProgressDialog();
            if (response != null && response.isSuccess()) {
                //Unit unit = response.getUnits().get(0);
                unit = response.getUnits().get(0);

                finishChecklist(unit, goodCondition);
            } else {
                showMessage(response.getMessage());
                saveChecklist();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            dismissProgressDialog();
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, unitCode);
}
```

With that I fetch the details of a vehicle. Then I have a method called validateMileage.

```
private void validateMileage(@NonNull Unit unit, @NonNull User user, @NonNull int mileage, int travels,
                             final boolean dayFinished) {

  List<Incident> incidents = mIncidentController.getIncidentList();
  Incident suspiciousMileageIncident = mIncidents.get(2);
  List<Manager> managers = mManagersController.findByIncidentId(suspiciousMileageIncident.getId());
..... 
}
```

If I just try to make calls like .getIncidentsList or .findByIncidentId I got an IOException when I wait for the response. But if I make the call in an AsyncTask, there is not errors.

Comment: share the code - your explanation isn't clear.

Comment: It's way too long, that's why I didn't post it.

Comment: select the relevant code, or create a pseudo code example - it will be very difficult to give concise answers without it. If you can't try to explain in steps current behaviour, and then expected/desired behaviour.

Comment: Done, I hope that's enough

Comment: No, I want to do the api calls without using AsyncTasks. But if I just send data to my api controllers outside an AsyncTask i got a IOException "Canceled".

Comment: Use an `Executor` - make sure to post any UI related events back on the UI thread though. The network operations can't be performed on the UI thread.